# How do I run Redis on Windows 32 bit?

Tags: windows, laravel, server, redis, driver

I have tried to set up Redis server on my windows 7 32 bit. I did not find a 32-bit supportive version of Redis. How can I do this?
Advance thanks.

Comment: cmd error!! **C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server --service-install 'redis-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.**

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? Can you help me out? I'm stuck with the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the .zip file to your hard drive.

Unzip the files into any location, such as ‘C:\Program Files\Redis\’.

Add the path of your Redis folder as a Windows ‘environment variable.’

Open your Command Prompt (ex: cmd.exe).

install redis server

```
redis-server --service-install
```

start redis server

```
redis-server --service-start
```

save and stop the Redis database

```
redis-server shutdown save
```

from command line please check if redis is up

```
redis-cli ping
```

Comment: Thank you @ankush. I followed all of the steps. But now I got this error in command prompt. **C:\Program Files\Redis>redis-server --service-install
'redis-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Comment: seems like your environment path has not been set, please set the path or you can use the command from its absolute location (where that file exists physically)

Comment: Still not working for 32 bit windows. It says doesn't support

Answer (score 0):

The source of redis not contains executable file like redis-server, you must compile it.

Redis not support windows officially, but microsoft had provided a fork in windows https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis.

The release it supported is only for 64bit windows, but the document says you can build it yourself with 32bit